# How to check for full browser configuration

Tags: browser, browser-addons, debug

I am helping a customer who is trying to use our company's website and failing in mysterious ways. Other users, even with the same browser type, are using our site without problems, while she can't. I have access to the user's User-Agent, but it doesn't tell me much; it just tells me that she is using the same browser (incl. version) than I am... and I have no problem using the site.

Is there any website, app... that I can tell this user to point her browser to, and will provide a full dump of the entire browser configuration? I know that [whaismybrowser.org](https://www.whatsmybrowser.org/), for example, shows things like OS version or screen resolution, but I am also looking at the extensions she has installed, whether she has Javascript on, etc.

Comment: If you don't find what you are looking for, may I suggest the user create a new user in Windows, which will have a different browser config? Also, some browsers have multiple similar versions (i.e., Firefox has Waterfox https://www.howtogeek.com/108608/6-alternative-browsers-based-on-mozilla-firefox/ and Chrome has Chromium https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium ) which your customer might try for testing purposes to isolate the problem.